# jQuery hide other td's that not contains

Tags: jquery, html-table

My problem is that I want to display only one id in the table.
I will show you an example:

```
|--ID1--|--text--|--text--|
|--   --|--text--|--text--|    //Still belongs to ID1
|--   --|--text--|--text--|    //Still belongs to ID1
|--ID2--|--text--|--text--|
|--   --|--text--|--text--|    //Still belongs to ID2
|--   --|--text--|--text--|    //Still belongs to ID2
```

So I want to display only the ID1 and the following td's belonging to this ID.

Do you have an idea ready for it?

**edit:**
you have to imagine I get a ready made html file from the server.
which looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qmr9K/

Now I want to display a selection, only the red fields.
the other should hide via jquery.
Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: How are you building the HTML? If using something like PHP to build it, then you can add an id to each table row and use jQuery to show/hide the appropriate rows. Another idea is to use jQuery to find table rows by relative position (selectors like .next, .parent, .find, .each, etc)

Comment: you have to imagine I get a ready made html file from the server.
which looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qmr9K/

Now I want to display a selection, only the red fields.
Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `rowspan` property.

```
<table border="1px"> 
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" valign="top">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" valign="top">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3KgEz/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td rowspan="3">ID1</td>
     <td> text1</td>
     <td> text2</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> text3</td>
     <td> text4</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> text5</td>
     <td> text6</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td rowspan="2">ID2</td>
     <td> text7</td>
     <td> text8</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> text9</td>
     <td> text10</td> 
   </tr>
</table>
</html>
```